# Way to load only Server data on webpage

Tags: jquery

I have tried using `window.location.reload();` which reload entire page while `history.go(0);` which clear only cache but not server content. I want to reload only the data that is coming from server. Is there any reload statement?

Comment: What do you mean, "server data"? You want (say) a form's entered data to remain constant while changing everything else around it? There's no automatic system for such thing.

Comment: Like say that php fetch a number from server and show on display. I want to reload only background php code so that reload will be faster and will displayed only changed data...

Comment: have you tried getting data through ajax?

Comment: No. I am directing generating through php [mysql]...

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to perform client side operations like this. I have found [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to be one of the best. jQuery can be used for this quite easily. jQuery has a few ways to do this. You can use the jQuery [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) function or the jQuery [getJson](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) function for this type of work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to study this:
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/
and maybe this:
http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/default.asp